# How to Center Text in Tabular with Custom Width?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

My code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{10em}|m{3em}|m{3em}|m{3em}|m{3em}|}
\hline
Equation & Linear Form & Y & X & m & c \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Compiling yields :

[image]

The texts are all aligned to the left. I would like to center all the texts but have no idea how. Thanks.

Comment: extend `m{3em}` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3em}` :-)

Answer (score 3):

As Zarko commented, with a simplified code and some vertical padding at the top of cells:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}m{10em}|*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3em}|}}
\hline
Equation & Linear Form & Y & X & m & c \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the > and \arraybackslash do? I'm guessing *{4} means it's repeated 4 times?

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo: `>{some code}` executes code on entering each cell in the column – so, here, each cell is centred  in its fixed width column. Similarly `<{some code}` executes code on leaving each cell (for  instance `>{$}m{3em}<{$}` would make each cell in the column be in maths mode). As to `\arraybackslash`,  it is to stipulate that, in cells in paragraph mode, `\\` means `\tabularnewline`, not a line break in the cell.